# Insertar en una tabla registros basados en el resultado de una consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando que insertar una fila nueva con unos datos por cada valor que de un SELECT.

Os dejo la última query que se me ha ocurrido pero que obviamente no funciona:

```
SET @postid = 
(SELECT post_id 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_value
LIKE '%barcelona%');

INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
                       VALUES
                       ( @postid, "geolocation_city", "Barcelona");
```

Osea lo que pretendo es que por cada resultado del select se cree una fila nueva en la tabla wp_postmeta con el valor meta_value = Barcelona y meta_key = geolocation_city y el post id deberia ser el de cada resultado del select.

Espero estar explicandome bien.

¿A alguien se le ocurre como podría hacerlo? Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Una opción es utilizar [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html).

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT A.post_id, "geolocation_city", "Barcelona"
FROM wp_postmeta A
WHERE A.meta_value LIKE '%barcelona%;'
```